# BASH Regex - matches validator but not when using grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am looking to search through a text file and return all lines that contain any words. I have tested this using an online tool (regex101.com) and it matches as I require. However when the regex is used in a `grep` command it is only returning lines that match a single word.

My command:

`grep \D original.txt`

File snippet:

```
229
229
kitchenDoor 229
229
229
230
230
230
230
230
kitchenDoor 230
230
231
525
525
525
526
cupCupboard 526
526
526
526
526
526
527
527
cupCupboard 527
527
527
kitchenDoor 538
```

What I am expecting returned is:

```
kitchenDoor 229
kitchenDoor 230
cupCupboard 256
cupCupboard 527
kitchenDoor 538
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
kitchenDoor 229
kitchenDoor 230
kitchenDoor 538
```

Comment: I'm curious to the down vote reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-P` parameter since `-P` (perl_regexp) only supports `\D`

```
grep -P '\D' original.txt
```

or

```
grep  '[^0-9]' original.txt
```

or

```
grep  '[^[:digit:]]' original.txt
```

or

```
grep  '[^[:digit:][:blank:]]' original.txt
```

Comment: Also, the quotes around `\D` are necessary. `\D` is the same as `D` in shell; `\\D` or `'\D'` passes two characters to `grep`.